# Check if the subscription has expired or not

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a webapp where I have been assigned a task of user subscription and to check if the subscription has expired or not. I'm doing this is PHP. I just need a basic idea of how to do this. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple approach. I'll share a code snippet I worked on. You can try it this way.Set a valid_upto field in your database. So when the user buys the subscription, store the value of the valid upto date into this field. Here's an example code snippet.

```
public function vendorcheckout($data)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO x3mdu_vendor_subscription(sub_id,vendor_id,sub_title,sub_amount,sub_duration,vendor_name,vendor_email,vendor_phone,vendor_address1,vendor_address2,vendor_city,vendor_state,payment_id,valid_upto,created) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,now())");
        $stmt->bind_param("iisisssissiiss", $data['sub_id'],$data['vendor_id'],$data['sub_title'],$data['sub_amount'],$data['sub_duration'],$data['vendor_name'],$data['vendor_email'],$data['vendor_phone'],$data['vendor_address1'],$data['vendor_address2'],$data['vendor_city'],$data['vendor_state'],$data['payment_id'],$data['valid_upto']);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        $last_id = $this->con->insert_id;
        if($result){
          return $last_id;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To check if the subscription is still active you can do it this way.

```
private function isSubscribed($vendor_id) {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT vs_id from x3mdu_vendor_subscription WHERE vendor_id = ? AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),valid_upto) < 0");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$vendor_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
    }
```

The `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),valid_upto)` will return a negative value until the valid_upto date comes. When the difference is greater than `0` 
that means your subscription has expired. Hope it helps

Comment: hey this is very helpful. It works for me. Thank you so much for the logic